# Gnosis Safe wallet transaction creation

Tags: web3js, gnosis-safe

Is there a way to achieve this scenario on JS application:

We want to implement a multisig wallet onto our application that is used to approve crypto transactions from an admin panel.  So our goal is, have one set of private keys only in the env that will be used for the first signature to be done by code, now the second signature we would like to only send the signature event to one of the other 2 owners via wallet address (connected via wallet connect) and not have either of those private keys stored anywhere in env or backend etc…

From the docs I have read, it’s stating to store all 3 owners private keys in the env file, we want to avoid this.